# Is there any way to use screen height and width in xml builder in Android?

Tags: android, height, width, screen

Is there any way to use screen height and width in xml builder in Android? I want to set View height to be half of screen without using view weight. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle screen height and width is to set view's sizes programmatically in onCreate() method.